# Vulkan error vkCreateDevice : VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT

Tags: vulkan

I am starting with Vulkan and I follow the Niko Kauppi's tutorial on Youtube.

I have an error when creating a device with vkCreateDevice, it returns VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT

Here some part of my code:

1. The call to vkCreateDevice

   ```
   _gpu_count = 0;
   vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &_gpu_count, nullptr);
   std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> gpu_list(_gpu_count);
   vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &_gpu_count, gpu_list.data());
   _gpu = gpu_list[0];

   vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(_gpu, &_gpu_properties);

   VkDeviceCreateInfo device_create_info = _CreateDeviceInfo();

   vulkanCheckError(vkCreateDevice(_gpu, &device_create_info, nullptr, &_device));
   ```

_gpu_count = 1 and _gpu_properties seems to recognize well my nvidia gpu (which is not up to date)

2. device_create_info

   ```
   VkDeviceCreateInfo _createDeviceInfo;

   _createDeviceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
   _createDeviceInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
   VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo _queueInfo = _CreateDeviceQueueInfo();
   _createDeviceInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = &_queueInfo;
   ```

I don't understand the meaning of the error: "A requested extension is not supported" according to Khronos' doc.

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you set the `enabledExtensionCount` and/or the `ppEnabledExtensionNames` members of `_createDeviceInfo`? that's where the requested extensions are put

Comment: @ratchetfreak no all I do with _createDeviceInfo is in the second code quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT` is returned when one of the extensions in [`enabledExtensionCount`, `ppEnabledExtensionNames`] vector you provided is not supported by the driver (as queried by `vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties()`).

Extensions can also have dependencies, so `VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT` is also returned when an extension dependency of extension in the list is missing there too.

If you want no device extensions, make sure `enabledExtensionCount` of `VkDeviceCreateInfo` is `0` (and not e.g. some uninitialized value).

I assume 2. is the whole body of `_CreateDeviceInfo()`, which would confirm the "uninitialized value" suspicion.

Usually though you would want a swapchain extension there to be able to render to screen directly.

Comment: Hello, I tried to add ppEnabledExtensionsNames, and I get another error, I don't know if the problem has the same origin or not. It is the exception 0xC0000005 Access violation, in Debug as in Realease, it is in 0x0000000069C492D8 (nvoglv64.dll) at 0x0000000000000014, it happens in vkCreateDevice. Thank you

Comment: [`enabledExtensionCount`, `ppEnabledExtensionNames`] is a poor man's vector. Provide appropriate `enabledExtensionCount` too, otherwise you may force the Vulkan command to read out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure your `VkDeviceCreateInfo` is zero filled, otherwise it may carry garbage to your `VkCreateDevice()` call.

Add following line just after declaring your VkDeviceCreateInfo:

```
memset ( &_createDeviceInfo, 0, sizeof(VkDeviceCreateInfo)  );
```

Some extensions are absolutely necessary, as swapchain one.

To retrieve available extensions do this:

```
// Available extensions and layers names
const char* const* _ppExtensionNames = NULL;    
// get extension names
uint32 _extensionCount = 0;
vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties( _gpu, NULL, &_extensionCount, NULL);
std::vector<const char *> extNames;
std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> extProps(_extensionCount);
vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(_gpu, NULL, &_extensionCount, extProps.data());
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < _extensionCount; i++) {
    extNames.push_back(extProps[i].extensionName);
}
 _ppExtensionNames = extNames.data();
```

Once you have all extension names in `_ppExtensionNames`, pass it to your deviceCreateInfo struct:

```
 VkDeviceCreateInfo  device_create_info ...
    [...]
    device_create_info.enabledExtensionCount = _extensionCount;
    device_create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = _ppExtensionNames;
    [...]
vulkanCheckError(vkCreateDevice(_gpu, &device_create_info, nullptr, &_device));
```

I hope it helps. 
Please double check above code, as I'm writing it by heart.

Comment: And please don't do this in production. You should only activate extensions that you actually need and never blindly activate extensions just because they are available on the platform. Extensions may severely slow down the program but you won't get anything back unless your code actively makes use of them. So the proper way is to keep lists of required and optional extensions for your application, check those against `vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties` and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For a very similar error I was missing the following debian packages:

```
libnvidia-rtcore libnvoptix1 packages in debian (possibly also Ubuntu) for raytracing support

libnvidia-ngx1 for DLSS support
```

Try it out.